# Sending multiple mp3's to SOX

Tags: shell, sox

Hi I am am wanting to send many different mp3's like an array to SOX for example

sox 1.mp3 2.mp3 N.mp3 out.mp3
sox num1.mp3 num2.mp3 numN.mp3 out2.mp3
sox n1.mp3 n2.mp3 nN.mp3 out3.mp3

How could I send all those at one time?Or Can I not do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash:

```
for f in *.mp3; { sox $f out$f; }
```

Comment: Nay way to do  this in php via exec()

Comment: In PHP you have to put this command between single quotes when you pass it to exec().

Answer (score 0):

For a short list:

```
sox {1,2,N}.mp3 out.mp3
sox num{1,2,N}.mp3 out2.mp3
sox n{1,2,N}.mp3 out3.mp3
```

For a range:

```
sox File{1..42}.mp3 out4.mp3
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with php by using exec().I have exec working very simply by doing this exec("./sox 1.wav 2.wav out.wav");

Comment: @james: The brace expansion is performed by the shell. You could probably get PHP to tell the shell to run the command and thus it would do the expansion. I would recommend, however, that you build a string using a loop in PHP and just pass it to `exec`. You probably should have said in your question that you're really trying to do this in PHP rather than tagging the question `[shell]`.